# Highcharts and php for a dynamic chart

Tags: php, json, dynamic, highcharts

I have been at this some time trying to get highcharts to chart some data returned by php.  I have done many searches and nothing works.  I can write the php to deliver the data however it needs to be but how do you get it to dynamically chart it?????

I can deliver it as:
[["1372875867","44.8782806"],["1372875885","46.2020226"]]
or
[[1372876686,44.0655823],[1372876693,43.3360596], etc ]

but how do I get the data from the php output into the dyname example they display?????

```
    !DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highstock Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" 
     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

Highcharts.setOptions({
    global : {
        useUTC : false
    }
});

// Create the chart
window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart : {
        renderTo : 'container',
        events : {
            load : function() {

                // set up the updating of the chart eachsecond
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function() {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), 
                    y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
            count: 1,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '1M'
        }, {
            count: 5,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '5M'
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
        }],
        inputEnabled: false,
        selected: 0
    },

    title : {
        text : 'Live random data'
    },

    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series : [{
        name : 'Random data',
        data : (function() {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;

            for( i = -999; i <= 0; i++) {
                data.push([
                    time + i * 1000,
                    Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                ]);
            }
            return data;
        })()
    }]
        });

    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="../../js/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
</body>
    </html>
```

my current php is:

```
    <?php
    //    include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/config/config.php");
    include("adodb5/adodb.inc.php");
    $connection = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO"); 
    $result_set = $connection->Execute("
            SELECT tag, TIME, value 
            FROM picomp 
            WHERE TIME >= '*-3m' AND tag = 'xxx:xx_xxx.xxx'
            ");

    $result_count = 0;
    //    $labels = array();
    while (!$result_set->EOF) {
$pidate = date("U", strtotime($result_set->fields[1]) );
if ($result_count <> 0){
print ",";
}else{
print "[";
}
    print "[".$pidate.",".$result_set->fields[2]."]";
    //        array_push("{$result_set->fields[2]}");
    $result_count = $result_count +1;
    $result_set->MoveNext();
    //  echo "testing";
    }
    print "];";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HighchartsPHP which is a wrapper for Highcharts, which basically allows you to write all that JS code in PHP. It's very useful and pretty simple to use.

[HighchartsPHP on GitHub](https://github.com/ghunti/HighchartsPHP)

Comment: I know it can be done without highchartsphp I was hoping someone could tell me how to modify their example to call the php program that delivers the data to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamp should be multiplied by 1000, and both values should be numbers.

Please familair with soultion, how to prepare JSON, because you only print "as JSON", but it is not.

Take look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php where some examples are introduced.

Comment: the Question is how do I tie the php with the html at the top?

Comment: Take look at the example http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing-data-from-a-database